# Rebar fails compiling / bulding from source on R16B02

Tags: erlang, rebar

Running Erlang R16B02 (its installed through source and compiled, erl is on path).

> Recompile: src/rebar_utils
>   Recompile: src/rebar_xref
>   Uncaught error in rebar_core: {'EXIT',
>                                  {undef,
>                                   [{crypto,start,[],[]},
>                                    {rebar,run_aux,2,
>                                     [{file,"src/rebar.erl"},{line,163}]},
>                                    {rebar,main,1,
>                                     [{file,"src/rebar.erl"},{line,58}]},
>                                    {erl_eval,do_apply,6,
>                                     [{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,569}]},
>                                    {escript,eval_exprs,5,
>                                     [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,856}]},
>                                    {erl_eval,local_func,5,
>                                     [{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,467}]},
>                                    {escript,interpret,4,
>                                     [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,774}]},
>                                    {escript,start,1,
>                                     [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,277}]}]}}
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [rebar: error exit on create-app: {crypto,start,\[\]}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742184/rebar-error-exit-on-create-app-crypto-start)

Comment: Did you install openssl-devel before compiling Erlang? See https://github.com/basho/rebar/issues/375

Comment: indeed, even tried yum install *openssl*

Comment: I can very that @legoscia is correct, crypto is missing from the erlang install and therefor can't be run. So the compile of the Erlang environment is the problem here.

Comment: This goes back to: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1023017 it seems...

Answer (score 0):

You have to install openssl-devel and recompile erlang.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to the problem with compiling Erlang R16 on RedHat reported in the [post on Erlang forum](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-February/076760.html). They propose to compile with:

```
CFLAGS="-DOPENSSL_NO_EC=1" ./configure && make && sudo make install
```